# Datepicker jquery по дате рождения

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Есть `Input`. При нажатии на него, нужно что бы сначала выбирал год, потом месяц, потом число, и вставлялось в `Input`. Пример работы [тут](http://lomonosov-msu.ru/rus/register/) В конце где выбрать дату рождения. Посмотрел [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) от jquery, но не нашел реализации. Есть готовые модули или вручную писать придется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что Вы привели в примере по ссылке очень сильно напоминает форк DateTime Picker для Bootstrap ([официальный сайт проекта](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php)).

Как вариант, можно попробовать настроить этот модуль или доработать его под себя.